# viewmodel inheritance and duplicate model references

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, mvvm, viewmodel

My question is: How to manage an inheritance chain of viewmodels?

My situation:

I'm having a standard **ViewModelBase** which only implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Furthermore I have a **BusinessObjectViewModel** which has a Guid, a **PersonBaseViewModel** which has the persons core data, a **CustomerViewModel** with customer related stuff and a **EmployeeViewModel** with employee related stuff.

All viewmodels certainly encapsulate a modelobject (Customer, Employee, PersonBase).

- BusinessObjectViewModel inherits from ViewModelBase
- PersonBaseViewModel inherits from BusinessObjectViewModel
- CustomerViewModel inherits from PersonBaseViewModel
- EmployeeViewModel inherits from PersonBaseViewModel

The model comes via constructor into the viewmodel.

If I use a constructor chain (every viewmodel makes a call to the base constructor) every viewmodel has it's model to return the encapsulated values from the model.

But I got to have a Model property in every viewmodel. In the case of CustomerViewModel I would have a reference in **CustomerViewModel**, one in PersonBaseViewModel and one in **BusinessObjectViewModel** for one and the same object. That sounds stupid to me.

Or I have to cast every property access in the upper viewmodels.

p.s. this is just a small cut-out of my model hierarchy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If BusinessObject and Person classes (and their VM counterparts) are abstract, then you could access the right Model like this:

```
public abstract class BusinessObjectViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    protected abstract BusinessObject BusinessObject { get; }

    protected BusinessObject Model { get { return this.BusinessObject; } }
}

public abstract class PersonViewModel : BusinessObjectViewModel
{
    protected abstract Person Person { get; }

    protected new Person Model { get { return this.Person; } }

    protected override sealed BusinessObject BusinessObject
    {
        get { return this.Model; }
    }
}

public class CustomerViewModel : PersonViewModel
{
    protected new Customer Model { get; set; }

    protected override sealed Person Person
    {
        get { return this.Model; }
    }
}

public class EmployeeViewModel : PersonViewModel
{
    protected new Employee Model { get; set; }

    protected override sealed Person Person
    {
        get { return this.Model; }
    }
}
```

This way every derived VM class provides a value for its base VM Model property by implementing abstract property and hides a base class Model property, so every VM works with Model property of an appropriate type (so no casting is required).

This approach has its benefits and drawbacks:

Benefits:

- No casting involved.

Drawbacks:

- Works only if base classes (BusinessObjectViewModel and PersonViewModel) are abstract because there must exist an abstract property that is implemented by the derived class and provides a Model instance to these base classes.
- Model property should not be accessed in the base class constructors, because constructor chaining goes from base class to the most derived class. The most derived class constructor will set Model, so base class constructors are called to early to see it. This can be avoided by passing Model as a parameter through constructors.
- BusinessObject and Person properties are unnecessary seen by the derived classes. EditorBrowsableAttribute might help here for Intellisense, but only when code is used by another assembly in different Visual Studio solution (this is Visual Studio specific behavior).
- Performance. When base classes access Model, code will go through a chain of virtual properties. But since since implemented abstract properties are marked as sealed, virtual table lookup should not be so much performance degrading.
- Doesn't scale nicely. For deep class hierarchies code would contain many unnecessary members.

Another approach would be:

```
public class BusinessObjectViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    protected BusinessObject Model { get; private set; }

    public BusinessObjectViewModel(BusinessObject model)
    {
        this.Model = model;
    }
}

public class PersonViewModel : BusinessObjectViewModel
{
    protected new Person Model { get { return (Person)base.Model; } }

    public PersonViewModel(Person model)
        : base(model)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomerViewModel : PersonViewModel
{
    protected new Customer Model { get { return (Customer)base.Model; } }

    public CustomerViewModel(Customer model)
        : base(model)
    {
    }
}

public class EmployeeViewModel : PersonViewModel
{
    protected new Employee Model { get { return (Employee)base.Model; } }

    public EmployeeViewModel(Employee model)
        : base(model)
    {
    }
}
```

Benefits:

- Base classes do not need to be abstract.
- Model can be accessed through base class constructors.
- No unnecessary additional properties.

Drawbacks:

- Casting.

Based on this analysis, I would go with a second option because fixing its only drawback, casting performance, would be unnecessary micro-optimization that would not be noticeable in WPF context.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Very nice explanation. I've chosen the second solution. Needs just few changes to my current datamodel.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer IMO is to use Generics, which might be as simple as

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase<TModel>  TModel : class{
    public TModel Model { get; protected set; }
}
```

The .net typing system will the know that your TModel is a Person, Customer, or whatever else without casting.

Let me know if you need more or if you want to post some code that needs help. And yes, it can be tricky getting your supertype heirarchies just right at first.

HTH,
Berryl

Comment: But this requires that every ViewModel class in hierarchy is generic. This can lead to some weird situations, like BusinessObjectViewModel<Customer> or BusinessObjectViewModel<Employee>, combinations of ViewModel and Model classes that should not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to expose your Model property in your ViewModels then you don't need to re-declare the Model properties in the ViewModel to expose them.  I normally expose the underlying Model object as a property in my ViewModels. In your case, for example in your EmployeeViewModel you would have a:

```
private Employee _MyEmployee;
public Employee MyEmployee {
get
{
return _MyEmployee;
}
set
{
_MyEmployee = value;
NotifyPropertyChanged(x=>x.MyEmployee);
}
```

Then your View could bind to your Employee properties through the MyEmployee property exposed in the ViewModel. As far as I understand it, the only case when you want to re-declare or wrap your Model Properties in your VM is when you need to do some data manipulation to be presented to your view.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing. But the BusinessObjectViewModel needs a Model to access the Id (Type System.Guid). And the PersonViewModel which inherits from BusinessObjectViewModel needs the model to access the person's properties. I know that the model property is inherited to PersonViewModel. But either I cast every property access inside the PersonViewModel or PersonViewModel gets an own reference to this object which leads to 2 properties for the same object.

Comment: Why not create a BusinessObjectBase or ModelBase class, which would be your Model base class. That way if all your Models inherit from that class you could encapsulate a ModelBase type property in your BusinessObjectViewModel and not have to redeclare it in your derived ViewModels?

Comment: That's also what I did. I think I gave too less informations :) There exist corresponding models to all the viewmodels. BusinessModelBase, Person, Employee, Customer. The BusinessModelBase has the Id, the Person hast the persondata and inherits from BusinessModel and so on. But the problem is, that in the PersonViewModel the Model property is of type BusinessModelBase. So I have to cast every property access (Model as Person).SurName. But I don't wanna do that. I think I'm looking for a solution other than inheritance. Maybe giving the specialized persons (Customer) a Person property.

Comment: Look for the "Dynamic Properties" section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff798279.aspx). Where do you need to do your type casting? I think if you bind to something like MyModelBaseProperty.SurName in your View XAML it works, it takes care of the casting automatically, from some tests I've done.

Comment: If you are using .NET 4.0 you may even consider declaring your encapsulated Model property with 'dynamic' type so you don't have to cast at all. I'd be interested to know how that works in MVVM.

Comment: I'll try that in the near future.