# MVC 5 EF 6 TPT and ViewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance, mvvm

I have my application rigged the following way...

Model and SubModel

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    // Other required properties
}

public class SubModel : BaseModel
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    // Other SubModel properties
}
```

In Context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<SubModel>().ToTable("SubModel");
}
```

Model binder that takes a string defined in my Create View and returns the appropriate SubModel.

```
public class BaseModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        if (modelType.Equals(typeof(BaseModelBinder)))
        {
            string typeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ModelType").AttemptedValue;
            Type type = Type.GetType(modelType.Namespace + "." + typeValue, true);
            object model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, type);
            return model;
        }

        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[Route("Create"), HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(string modelType)
{
    // Get Model Type from modelType and convert into appropriate type
    // to retrieve the proper editor template.
    Type type = Type.GetType("MyApp.Models." + modelType);
    object model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    return View(model);
}

[Route("Create"), HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(BaseModel baseModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userId = Convert.ToInt32(IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(User.Identity));
        baseModel.UserId = userId;
        baseModel.DatePosted = DateTime.UtcNow;
        // If this is a SubModel, an insert is made into table BaseModel as well
        // as an insert into the SubModel table for SubModel specific properties
        // linked by the Id of the BaseModel as the SubModel Id
        db.BaseModel.Add(baseModel);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }        
    return View(baseModel);
}
```

Create View

```
@model MyApp.Models.BaseModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType())
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    </div>
}
```

Editor Template For SubModel

```
@model MyApp.Models.SubModel
// Form Stuff
```

This all works fine and dandy. I can pull up the Create View and display the proper template for the SubModel requested and when I post it, the Create HttpPost action takes it as it's of Type BaseModel and inserts into both the SubModel table and BaseModel table. Now what I'd like to do is create ViewModels for my BaseModel and SubModels to keep the domain models clean.

**ISSUE**

If I change my controller to return a ViewModel, when I Post to the Create Action, it isn't the correct Type, since it doesn't inherit from BaseModel.

How can I create a ViewModel for the BaseModel that only exposes certain properties that I can Data Annotate for client-side validation and as well create SubViewModels for SubModels and have the SibViewModel also be of Type SubModel which will also be of Type BaseModel since SubModels inherit from BaseModel?

I also want the SubViewModels to inherit the BaseModelViewModel properties since every SubModel will require parts of the BaseModel.

Looking at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723922/viewmodel-inheritance-and-duplicate-model-references) , the answer that speaks about generics is possibly the path I'm looking to take but not sure how to implement it properly.

I need to take the ViewModel, pass it to the Create [HttpPost] controller and have that insert into the BaseModel table (or SubModel and BaseModel depending on the ViewModel).

Long post, and might be confusing the way I've worded it since I'm having a hard time describing things I'm trying to accomplish sometimes. I've been spending hours upon hours reading on ASP.NET MVC and it seems the more I read, the more I question my design patterns because there are so many alternatives to accomplish the same task that each have pros and cons, dependent on so many factors... My mind is overloaded. Please help :]

Answer (score 3):

> How can I create a ViewModel for the BaseModel that only exposes certain properties that I can Data Annotate for client-side validation and as well create SubViewModels for SubModels and have the SibViewModel also be of Type SubModel which will also be of Type BaseModel since SubModels inherit from BaseModel?

If I understand you correctly, then you can't. That would require your SubViewModel to inherit from BaseViewModel *and* from SubModel, which would require multiple inheritance. And that's not available in .NET.

I also wouldn't recommend it, even if it was possible. I believe the reason you want to do it like that is to reuse as much code as possible, and not having to maintain the SubViewModel to be a 'mirror' of your domain model. But is this really the right way to go?

Consider this: Let's assume your SubViewModel did inherit from your domain model. That would result in all properties and methods to be available in your viewmodel and consequently in your views. It would also result in all *future* properties and methods to be available in your views. You can no longer control what properties and methods are available to your views, without changing your domain model. You can add new properties and methods to your viewmodel without adding them to your domain model, but you cannot remove those inherited from the domain model. I would see this as a drawback. Ideally, you want view models that expose exactly the data the view needs to accomplish its task, and not any more. Remember that the idea of a 'view model' is to have a model that's useful for the specific view and the task they should accomplish.

**There is also another drawback**. To enable client side validation, you need to decorate the properties with Data Annotations attributes. If your SubViewModel inherits from your domain model to reuse the properties, such as Name, ZipCode etc, then you need to put these attributes on the properties in the domain model. So now you have attributes related to MVC Client Side validation in your domain model. If you later decided to reuse your domain model in another project that used another technology, where you didn't use MVC, then these properties would be almost useless. (I say almost, because in a specific scenario, you could be lucky and find some alternative validation framework that could utilize the Data Annotations attributes, but that is not guaranteed) **In effect, you would have 'polluted' your domain model with something that is irrelevant for the domain.**

Now, I'm not saying that validation is irrelevant to the domain, because it most certainly is not. But I would consider using a more general way of validating in the domain layer, than using Data Annotations attributes. (Fluent Validation for example)

Besides, if you need a bit more complicated validation (Now or in the future), then you'll pretty quickly find Data Annotations attributes lacking. You can implement your own attributes, but it won't be pretty if you need more complicated validation, for example conditional validation. ('This property should follow these rules if that other property...')

Also, if you at a later point find out that you need to use another validation framework in MVC that doesn't use Data Annotations attributes, then you need to change the domain model to remove the attributes.

Do you see the pattern here? You want to change something in the UI (MVC) and because of that you need to change something in the domain model. This is really not ideal. You want the domain layer and the UI layer to be as decoupled as possible.

I know I might have gone off on a tangent here, and it's maybe not directly answering your question. But **my point is just that I think you should reconsider coupling your domain model and your MVC application together, by having your view models inherit from your domain model.**

And actually, if you did that, the problem you described above would disappear.

Answer (score 1):

***Disclaime this is just an Advance Comment***

Like René pointed out it doesn't look like your problem is the real problem here

Because the ViewModel should encapsulate the Model and not inherit it. That's basically how the VM-M-Part of MVVM works

normally a VM should look similar to this

```
public class VM
{
    M model;

    public M Model
    {
        get { return model; }
        set { model = value; }
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get { return model.ID; }
        set { model.ID = value; }
    }

    #region cTor
    public VM(M m)
    {
        this.Model = m;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

but to separate your Model-Laver from ViewModle-Layer you could use an Interface 
so `M` could be an `Class` or `Interface` depending on your need's.

Comment: I see where you're going here, I'm going to research into this more. Thanks for the help.